# ReactJS: Passing component in as a property

Tags: reactjs

I create a Dropdown Menu and am trying to pass it to another component:

```
var DropDownButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            stage: 'Select'
        }
    },

    change: function(e){
        this.setState({
            stage: e.target.value
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div key={i}>
                <select  id='dropdown' onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Option1 </option>
                    <option value="2">Option2 </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

I'm trying to pass this menu into `CreateCandidate`:

```
return (
            <div>
                {pageHeaderInstance}
                <CreateCandidate addCandidate = {this.addCandidate} />
                <ShowTable people= {this.state.people} />
            </div>
        )
```

Inside `CreateCandidate` I create new objects and I want to include the dropdown menu as part of it.

How can I pass the entire component into another component? I was thinking of something like this:

```
<CreateCandidate addCandidate = {this.addCandidate} dropdownmenu = { ..add dropdownButton component..}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass components around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass created jsx component as simple as

```
<CreateCandidate addCandidate = {this.addCandidate} dropdownmenu = {<DropDownButton/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct Approach would be to import the component in the `CreateCandidate` Component and then using it rather than passing the component from parent

Import it like

```
import {DropDownButton} from '/path/to/DropDownButton';
```

and use it as `<DropDownButton/>`

Also make sure you export the DropDownButton component like

```
module.exports = DropDownButton;
```